# firefox developer tools search console option missing

Tags: firefox, frontend, mozilla, firefox-developer-tools

How can I search in console window of developer tools of firefox, the same way we can do in chrome/chromium.
In the later, we can search the console like a normal text file as well as we can filter output.
But in firefox we can only filter output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching within the Console is currently (as of Firefox 75) not possible, only filtering. The implementation of a search is tracked in [bug 992594](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992594).